# panic: runtime error: slice bounds out of range when using mongorestore.exe?

Tags: mongodb, slice, mongorestore

When I try restoring certain collections using mongorestore.exe I get that error.

```
mongorestore.exe --collection user --db dbName dump/dbName/user.bson
```

Is this to do with file names being too long? Smaller collections seem to restore fine but the bigger ones fail with that error.

Comment: Did you figure this one out? Have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me because I created the index on an collection using the wrong capitalisation, instead of currentgames the index was created on currentGames.
Thus, when mongodump ran, the metadata file for currentgames was overwritten by the metadata from the currentGames collection and on restore this error occurred

Be sure to check your capitalisation and the collections you have in the database.

Hope this helps!